# Parentheses symbol with \MnSymbol

Tags: symbols, mnsymbol

**Original:**

[image]

How can I do this type of Parentheses, without removing the `\usepackage{MnSymbol}`? Help me
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\begin{document}

$ \qty(\frac{2}{3}) $

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there anyone to help?

Comment: May I know the purpose of using the package `MnSymbol`, is this only to get the `Minion` font or something else ?

Comment: How to draw this parentheses symbol, without removing this package I Just wondered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try with this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}

\makeatletter
\DeclareSymbolFont{spllargesymbols}{OMX}{cmex}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{spllargesymbols}{bold}{OMX}{cmex}{b}{n}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{(}{\mathopen}{letters}{46}{spllargesymbols}{0}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{)}{\mathclose}{letters}{47}{spllargesymbols}{1}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$ \qty(\frac{2}{3}) $

\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Thanks sir, that's what I wanted. Thank you for your support @MadYuvi

Comment: @cufcuf I've modified slightly because modified tags should not affect others...I'm glad to know that I could help you...

Comment: When I added the `e^{f\qty(x)}`, parantheses is not working @MadyYuvi